# How do I physically switch hard drives fast?

Tags: hard-drive

I have multiple hard drives and I need to change different hard drive frequently for testing (the motherboard only support 4 hard drives).
It is very annoy, because each time I have to open the box and plug and unplug the data cables and power cables.
Is there any solution for it without loss the speed?

Comment: Only other solution is a usb 3.0 docking station for sata drives. If you need max speed they have to be connected to the motherboard. I use one of these>>>>https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-5Bay-USB-3-0-SATA-HDD-SSD-Docking-Station-Offline-Clone-2-5-3-5-Hard-Drive/114341407218?hash=item1a9f4769f2:g:IyoAAOSwY35fK8Zb

Comment: I second USB 3 docking stations for SATA drives. I have one with two slots right next to me, works like a charm. Just insert the drive you need.

Comment: Camino, I would label your question differently: "How do I physically switch hard drives fast?" When I first read your question it appeared to me as a question about storage technology.

Comment: @NasirRiley No, just some ordinary hard disks.

Comment: @Moab how can you know if there is an "only other" solution? how do you know there aren't others you havent' run into?  BTW I recall years ago 5.25" bays that you could put a 3.5" hard drive into, and pull the bays in and out quickly and easily. They were very useful in the days of Windows 9X when you could change a hard drive running windows 9X from one computer to another regardless of motherboard chipset and windows would still load.

Comment: Look up swappable drive bay Here is an example of one made by Startech https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81ZiQwn%2BBUL._AC_SL1500_.jpg   See it's a 5.25"  bay and you plug a 3.5" drive into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118943/discussion-between-barlop-and-camino).

Comment: you dont even need to unplug anything, usually motherboard has a lot of usb ports